# Browser doesn't rewrite URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite an url
my website contents only html pages, so it's so simple

sturcture:

```
[/]
---[visit]
------index.html
---[...]
---index.html
```

the original is :

```
www.example.com/visit
```

i want to rewrite the url and display it in the address bar as follow

```
https://example.com/visit-italy-in-summer/
```

i'm using the following rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
## Redirect all to https non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

## Redirecd index.html & php to /
RewriteCond     %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(html|php)                               [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*?)index\.(?:html|php)$                      /$1             [R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteRule     visit-italy-in-summer     visit           [R=301]
```

everything works perfectly except when i visit

```
https://example.com/visit-italy-in-summer
```

the browser address bar shows

```
https://example.com/visit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You last rule is reversed, it should be:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /visit[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ visit-italy-in-summer [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^visit-italy-in-summer/?$ visit/ [L,NC]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: when i do this i get Error 404 not found

Comment: ok check updated answer, test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: didnt work, i got the same problem as mentioned in my question, rewrite works but the original url is shown

Comment: Since `visit` is a directory it will need a trailing slash also in the rule. See updated rule (**test it after clearing your browser cache**)

Comment: this worked fine! but the css and pictures links are now broken. under each subdirectory i use a seperated css file and images directory because each page has its layout

Comment: For css/js etc you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: no, under `visit` directory i have `visit/style.css` and `vist/images`

Comment: First of all this is the problem asked in question. Secondly if css/image files are in `/visit/` then use `<base href="/visit/" />`